# How to create a animated silhouette?

Tags: rendering, animation

I am making an intro for 'The Tim Show'. The thing is I've only modeled a good head and that's mainly it.

The intro will be like shadows of a person, with a drill in a hand, etc. Look [here](http://webneel.com/video/tv-broadcast-news-intro-animation-after-effects) at 1:07 on the earth. Here is an image of it: [image: Silhoette]

(I do not want a globe/sphere, only on a screen)

But it will be with Blender (yes!!) and will not be on an earth. I may enhance it with some other stuff.

The thing is I don't know where to start and I need a fast solution as I am under pressure.

Thanks in advance

Comment: What about an animated texture?

Comment: By mainly a head, that is the thing I have ever done in Blender (that head is not in the intro)

Comment: how long is the clip supposed to be?

Comment: @JebediahKerman: As long as the beginning of this: http://revision3.com/tbhs/double-decker-3d-printer-part1

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can use a human mesh with a shrinkwrap modifier on a plane. Let me show you an exemple:

First if you want to use an human body you can create it with [makehuman](http://www.makehuman.org/) and import it in blender with all the skeleton. Then you can create the animation of your human.
[image: Human from makehuman]

After that you can add the surface where you want your silhouette to be. For the exemple I used a plane.

[image: Human with plane surface]

Now you can add the shrinkwrap modifier on your human.

[image: shrinkwrap modifier]

Now it's time to render. I've done the render with cycle, in blender internal you have problem with the superposition of the mesh like this:[image: problem render]

So here is the final render with cycle:

[image: cycle render]

Here is the video example on [youtube](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=UTQB4yHPI5Y&feature=youtu.be).

And of course it works with animation. Hope this can help you.

Comment: Thanks so much! WHat is the license for using makehuman? Thanks! I speak french too at home, I live in the UK!

Comment: @TimTimmy See their [website](http://makehuman.org/doc/node/makehuman_mesh_license.html).